# model variables in Tensorflow's batch_norm

Tags: tensorflow

The documentation online says moving_average and moving_variance are both model_variables, and tf.model_variables() returns tensors of the type local_variables. Does that mean model_variables are not saved when I save my state?

I'm trying to apply batch normalization to a couple of 3D convolution and fully connected layers. I trained my network with batch_norm and saved a checkpoint file, but when I went to restore my saved state, it said moving_mean could not be located. The exact error was, when TF went to assign the restored value to moving_mean, the shape of the lhs tensor, [], could not be reconciled with the that of the rhs, [20].

The graph restores fine when I don't add batch_norm around my layers. 
I'm planning to add a global variable at the end of training that saves my moving_mean and moving_variance values. Is this the way TF intended for me to use batch_norm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The variables moving_mean and moving_variance were not in my saved stated because I had set updates_collections to its default. Since I never included a control dependency when I ran the layers, those variables never were updated.

The code to include is:

```
from tensorflow.python import control_flow_ops

update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
if update_ops:
    updates = tf.tuple(update_ops)
    total_loss = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(updates, total_loss)
```

Or set

```
updates_collection=None
```

to for in-place updates.

See [the API description](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm.md) and [current github discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4361) for more information.